# Eclipse XML formatter inserts unneeded line breaks

Tags: xml, eclipse, formatter

Eclipse Version: Indigo Service Release 2

I can't get my XML formatter to do the job right.

When I apply formatter to this

```
<execution>
<id>compile</id>
<phase>compile</phase>
<goals>
<goal>compile</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
```

i get this

```
<execution>

    <id>
compile
    </id>

    <phase>
compile
    </phase>

    <goals>

        <goal>
compile
        </goal>
    </goals>

</execution>
```

I want it to format like this:

```
<execution>
    <id>compile</id>
    <phase>compile</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```

I tried different options in `XML -> XML Files -> Editor` but none seems to work.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in Android Editor, that was the default XML editor for me.

Two options to resolve this issue:

- Use Eclipse XML editor `Open With -> XML Editor`
- Disable "Standard Android XML style" in `Android -> Editors`