# Eclipse XML formatter adds whitspace inside elements

Tags: eclipse, xml-editor

Eclipse's XML formatter does something rather annoying.

It turns this:

```
<timestamp>2009-10-20 00:00:00.000</timestamp>
```

Into

```
<timestamp>2009-10-20 00:00:00.000
</timestamp>
```

Quite harmless typically except with, for example, Apache CXF who will now try to parse the whitespace in the timestamp and will throw parse exceptions!

How can I get it to stop doing this? Everything else about Eclipse's XML formatter works awesome.

Note: This question is not a duplicate of [Eclipse XML formatter inserts unneeded line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106037/eclipse-xml-formatter-inserts-unneeded-line-breaks) This one references android XML editor which I'm not using.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with the latest Eclipse release (Mars). Can you add a screenshot of your **Preferences** > **XML** > **XML Files** > **Editor**?

Comment: I'm using all the Eclipse Mars defaults.

Comment: The preferences are stored with the workspace, and I can't reproduce with a brand new workspace created with Mars. Can you think of anything else that might be affecting the behavior? Can you post with a complete XML file that exhibits the problem for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. It was the "new line" functionality. Eclipse takes it upon itself to add new lines to the XML *even when inside an element* if past the "max characters per line." When I increased the character count to 9999 it fixed the issue.